# VBA or moving data from one column to another column without using copy paste

Tags: excel

I am new to VBA's, I want to move data from one column to the next column. In Column A there is information underneath each other which I want to split into columns next to each other

There is a bunch of company names and item descriptions and PO numbers all listed under column A.
So I want to take all the different company names and put it in column B
Take all the different item codes and put them in column C
And take all the PO numbers and put them in Column D

What will be the best way to do this?

Comment: How do you identify which items are company names, which are item descriptions, PO numbers? Are they always listed in exactly the same order name, item, PO, name, item, PO, etc., with exactly one item and one PO for each company?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Below screenshot is how what the data looks like when it is exported into Excell.  Each Customer has a code allocated to it. the document number is the order number and then each item has an item code.

Comment: I want to organize the spreadsheet. so that all information are next to each other